# Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() not outputting correct file version

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I see that the definition of GetExecutingAssembly() is that it returns the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.

The code that I have is

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

However, when I run the program, that line always returns version that is different from the file version on the DLL. So I see that the DLL has file version and product version of 7.1 but that line above always returns 7.0

How could this possibly happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this , to get file version and not assembly version

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
var version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: I see! I think I may have solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, i had the same problem. This solved it!

Comment: Although this made my Xamarin.Forms app crash in release mode, debug mode worked fine...